# Build an input pipeline with tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two lists of paths
One call training and one called Test.

I want to Build two input pipelines with tf.data.
One called train_dataset and one called test_dataset
Here is my code :

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(train_set)
train_dataset = train_set.map(load_image_train,
                              num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)


def load_image_train(a_training_datapoint):
  real_image_path, drawing_path = a_training_datapoint.split('&')
  real_image = convert_images_to_tensor(real_image_path)
  drawing_image = convert_images_to_tensor(drawing_path)
  real_image, drawing_image = random_jitter(real_image, drawing_image)
 real_image, drawing_image = normalize(real_image, drawing_image)
 return real_image, drawing_image
```

the error I am getting is saying :

```
InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'No files matched pattern: gdrive/My Drive/DrawingDataSet/FacePictures/19/IMG_1835.JPG&gdrive/My
```

I am getting this error because I combined to images together with an @ as you can see.
I did that because I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix) but with my Dataset.

how do I make my train_dataset but keep my two images group together ?

Comment: Did you fix your issue? I am getting the same error with my file path.

Comment: no, I never did